# Semantic UI input element in error state inside form

Tags: css, forms, semantic-ui

Take a look at the [example for an input in error state](https://semantic-ui.com/elements/input.html#error). As you can see the CSS will make the input appear with error styles as soon as it has `ui input error` as classes.
However when placed inside a `ui form`, a very common usecase I would assume, the very same classes are overruled by a more specific selector coming from the `ui form`: `.ui.form input[type=...]`. Causing the `error` class to have no effect at all.

I did try to add `error` as state to the parent `form` div as well - no effect. To the parent `segment` - no effect.

Demo showing the working version without form: https://jsfiddle.net/hahz35ka/

Demo showing the non-working version with form: https://jsfiddle.net/hahz35ka/1/

Why? What is the supposed usage of inputs with errors inside forms?

Comment: demos for both cases added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to do an error state in a form is to wrap the input in a `<div>` with `.field .error` classes like the following :

[[demo]](https://codepen.io/SaadRegal/pen/GvOwaQ?editors=1010)

```
<div class="ui form">
    <div class="ui input">
        <div class="field error">
          <input placeholder="Search..." type="text">
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check out [Form Validation](https://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/form.html) for more details